# Running a function after a certain period of time without holding up the execution thread

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been working on a Discord bot using Discord.js and I've run into a frustrating limitation of Javascript that I'm trying to find a workaround for.

Essentially, I come to a point in my code where I want to wait a set period of time.

Currently, I have this implemented in my code as

```
while (new Date().getTime() < targetTime)
{
    //Waiting
}
```

The problem is that other aspects of my code can not function while this while loop is in action.
For example, I have an event listener for anytime a user sends a message in Discord, but the listener does not work while the while loop is executing.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
     //stuff happens here
}
```

Any recommendations on how to get this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.js wait before send message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627508/discord-js-wait-before-send-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expected behavior, the main thread is "busy" getting a current date on every thick.
So he cannot do anything else, because js is single-threaded.

You can use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) npm package which implements a better algorithm for observing the current date.

```
const date = new Date(2020, 1, 22, 12, 0, 0);

schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
  console.log('job is running');
});
```